# HtmlAgilityPack check amount of tables and find their "heading"

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to extract information from within a DIV that contains all between 2-6 tables with HtmlAgilityPack.

As long as there are the same amount of tables I can get the information without any problems by using

```
var thirdTable = res.SelectSingleNode("table[3]");
```

Each table contains tds and the first one contains the name I want to check for. At the moment it's done by

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr bgcolor="#505050">
            <td colspan="2" class="white">
                <b>Character Deaths</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

var charTest = thirdTable.ChildNodes[0].InnerText.StartsWith(checkInfo);
```

but since the amount of tables differs from time to time I cannot extract the information without having a NullReferenceException.

How can I check the amount of tables then tell which tables that exists?

EDIT:

```
       var URLCharacter = "http://www..." + tbSearch.Text;
       HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
       htmldocObject = doc.Load(URLCharacter);
       //Find the right contentdiv
       var res = htmldocObject.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='BoxContent']");
```

Comment: Do you want to select the text "Character Deaths" ? In other words, Do you want to select the text in the 1st cell of all tables, within an element represented by `res`?

Comment: I want to check the amount of tables there are and then check which "header" they have, because within there's a lot more data that I want to extract. The problem I'm facing is that there are not always the same amount of tables within the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is *attempt* to get the third table by selecting all tables, skipping the first two, then take the next one (the third).  If you get an element, do what you want with it, otherwise do nothing.

```
var thirdTable = res.Elements("table").Skip(2).FirstOrDefault();
if (thirdTable != null)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

If you're having trouble using the `Elements()` method, you could use `SelectNodes()` with appropriate xpath for a replacement.

```
var thirdTable = res.SelectNodes("table").Skip(2).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: For some reason I'm getting the error 
Method not found: 'Int32 System.Environment.get_CurrentManagedThreadId()'. on this line "var thirdTable = res.Elements("table").Skip(2).FirstOrDefault();"

Comment: ive researched some, currently im using .net framework 4 (without client profiling), do I need a newer version?

Comment: No that _should_ work with 3.5 and up however due to that exception, targeting .net 4.5 should resolve it. That exception is new to me. I see that call to [`Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentmanagedthreadid%28v=vs.110%29) which is a .net 4.5 thing. Is that a call you're making or is that being called by HAP? It would have to be removed/replaced if you're targeting .net 4. It could be coming from however you generated `res`. Would you mind including the code for that?

Comment: I've edited now, however that variable has worked all the time before while I've been trying to work it out, maybe does not work together with elements. It also seems that the "Elements" part is causing it as I've tried without the Skip() and FirstOrDefault(). cheers

Comment: You know, it could be the build of HAP that you're using. I noticed that the [latest versions target .net 4.5](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) so you probably shouldn't be using them. Or maybe it could be considered a bug? You could either target .net 4.5 or get a version of HAP that targets .net 4. Either way, the `Elements()` call can be replaced with the equivalent `SelectNodes()` call.

Comment: Thank you very much! Elements() works fine, the issue was my reference (HAP 4.5)